Repeated crashing and loss of function in terminal
I'm not sure where to start to work out this issue, its seems so broad.  Ubuntu itself is repeatedly crashing with a pop up saying it has stopped working and would I like to send an error message.
When I go into the terminal pretty much any command line I try to run prompts the error message:
E: Type '“deb' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/onedrive.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
Even for very simple commands like checking for updates, or any other task I've done many times.  The only command I've been able to make it run is sudo reboot.  I'm not sure why this and nothing else I've tried seems to function.
As you can probably tell, I'm a very new user, any advice on how to go about troubleshooting or repairing this would be very gratefully received, so far I've tried to check for updates, run an upgrade to ubuntu, and several of the commands found under apt get, but all prompt the same above error message.
I'm using Ubuntu 23.04, which I've seen isn't being updated any more, could that cause this?  And if so how do I update when none of the commands will run?
UPDATE:  I appreciate everyone's comments about what could be causing the issue.  Does anyone know how I could go about fixing these?  Especially updating the Ubuntu, but I also need to either remove the onedrive or at least stop it from searching for the debs there?  None of the online tutorials have provided any clarity
Sorry for the confusion, I have been away from work for several months and have returned to inherit this chaos

Ubuntu 23.04 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/01/26/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-reached-end-of-life-on-january-25-2024/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Your error (to me) implies an error made by a user on your machine with sudo rights, however problems with an EOL source can be expected; as after EOL the main archive is moved, and the mirrors are free to drop support, as are any 3rd party sources... thus errors with sources are expected; but not the specific issue you mentioned.  Your error tells you the problem, error is on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/onedrive.list which is a file that was added to your system by a user with sudo rights..  You're off-topic now on this site due to your EOL release.

Disclosure: I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive
There are 2 things going on here:

When installing 'onedrive' on Ubuntu (and distributions based on Debian|Ubuntu) you must follow these instructions: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/ubuntu-package-install.md - following any other instruction from elsewhere will lead you to problems.
As of time of writing (15-8-2024) the OpenSuSE Repository key has expired. The OpenSuSE package maintainer is aware of the issue and this will be fixed in due course (potentially after the weekend 17|18 August).

Please do not open a 'bug' report for this key expiry - first, it is not a bug, and secondly there is a discussion post that can be contributed to.
Edit: OpenSuSE Repository key has been updated and packages rebuilt and resigned. There should be no issue anymore.
Issue References:

https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/issues/2773
https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/issues/2775
https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/discussions/2774

Valid Temporary Workaround for Ubuntu 24.x
Ubuntu 24.x currently has the latest release client (v2.4.25) in the main Ubuntu repositories. For the moment, users on Ubuntu 24.x can install the client from there, however when v2.5.0 is released, anyone who has installed this way will need to utilise the OpenSuSE repository to get the new client version that includes many bug fixes and major performance enhancements such as multi-threaded activity.
The v2.5.x client series is currently at RC3, and the details regarding this can be found here: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/discussions/2770

The error message means that you did not follow the instructions carefully enough while installing OneDrive, so you made an error. Certain skills and learning are required to fix it.
But that's a small problem.
Your BIG problem is that your 23.04 system is past EOL. It is no longer receiving security patches. It may be vulnerable, and should not be on a network.
Remove all non-Ubuntu software (including OneDrive), and disable all the apt sources that non-Ubuntu software came from. Release-upgrade your system to 24.04.  (It won't be easy -- you missed the easy window).
You can reinstall OneDrive properly after you have successfully migrated to a supported release of Ubuntu.
